# Url in Route Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to use url like: `http:localhost:8000/api/students/?key=value`.

My API is set up as follows:

`Route::get('students/{key},'Controller@method')`

but my url is: `http:localhost:8000/api/students/value`
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you can share with us to help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the key as a $_GET param you want to change your route to just be:

```
Route::get('students/,'Controller@method')
```

That way you can use `http:localhost:8000/api/students/` and pass any parameters you want

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Route :

```
Route::get('students,'Controller@method')
```

in Your Controller use

> $request->input('key') or $request->query('key')

```
public function method(Request $request){
   $value = $request->query('key');
   $value2 =$request->input('key');
   echo $value;
   echo $value2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('students/{key}','Controller@method');
    // here come api-prefixed routes
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes